# Predefined input source per window in Gnome

Tags: gnome3

I have two input sources configured in my Gnome installation (Spanish and UK English). I'm able to change between theme easily using the Super+Spc shortcut, and I have configured using Gnome tweak tool that every window in my environment can have its own input source (for example, I use Spanish in Pidgin, but UK English for terminals).

This is fine for me, but I want to go one step further and I want to pre-configure that every time I open a program, its input source will be the same. Right now, when I open the Terminal, I need to actively change the input source for that window. I'm looking for a way to say "every time I open a terminal, use UK Engglish input source" instead doing it manually.

Do you know if that possibility exist in Gnome? Do you know any 3rd party program that can make the magic?

Comment: You can write a mini shellscript for this. Hint: `xprop -spy -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW`

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/79319/how-to-change-language-of-a-specific-application      
"$ cat ~/bin/gnome-terminal
#!/bin/sh
export LANGUAGE=en_US
exec /usr/bin/gnome-terminal $@" except change US to UK